# How to fix breakpoint showing up on memory state issue?

Tags: ios, breakpoints

My break points are showing up over the memory state but I want to see them within code so that I can perform debugging. See the attached image and let me know how it can be fixed?[image]

Comment: Did you pressed `F8` or `F7` to step into the method call or the breakpoint is stopping right there ? Also make sure you don't have a symbolic breakpoint enabled.

Comment: @danypata symbolic breakpoint? How can I disable them?

Answer (score 1):

Figured Out:
See the attached image and un-check the "Show Disassembly while Debugging[image]"